# Weblogic + Stateless Local Bean + DataSource Injection mistake

Tags: weblogic, ejb-3.0, local, stateless-session-bean

I Have a Stateless Local Bean like that:

```
@Stateless(name="GerencialFacadeBean", mappedName="GerencialFacade")
public class GerencialFacadeBean implements GerencialFacadeBeanLocal {

    @Resource(name="jdbc/adq_sistint", mappedName = "jdbc/adq_sistint")
    private DataSource dataSource;
.. }
```

So, when I take use of this bean I got the follow exception:

```
Caused by: com.bea.core.repackaged.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Dependency injection failure: can't find the bean definition about class interface javax.sql.DataSource; nested exception is com.bea.core.repackaged.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No unique bean of type [javax.sql.DataSource] is defined: No beans of type javax.sql.DataSource; owner=com.bea.core.repackaged.springframework.context.support.GenericApplicationContext@5d225fc1: display name [com.bea.core.repackaged.springframework.context.support.GenericApplicationContext@5d225fc1]; startup date [Mon Oct 15 16:30:12 BRT 2012]; parent: com.bea.core.repackaged.springframework.context.support.GenericApplicationContext@885e019
    at com.oracle.pitchfork.inject.Jsr250Metadata.applyInjections(Jsr250Metadata.java:241)
    at com.oracle.pitchfork.inject.Jsr250Metadata.inject(Jsr250Metadata.java:223)
    at com.oracle.pitchfork.inject.Jsr250Metadata.injectAndPostConstruct(Jsr250Metadata.java:253)
    at com.oracle.pitchfork.inject.Jsr250MetadataBeanPostProcessor.postProcessAfterInstantiation(Jsr250MetadataBeanPostProcessor.java:40)
    at com.bea.core.repackaged.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:957)
    at com.bea.core.repackaged.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:470)
    ... 66 more
Caused by: com.bea.core.repackaged.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No unique bean of type [javax.sql.DataSource] is defined: No beans of type javax.sql.DataSource; owner=com.bea.core.repackaged.springframework.context.support.GenericApplicationContext@5d225fc1: display name [com.bea.core.repackaged.springframework.context.support.GenericApplicationContext@5d225fc1]; startup date [Mon Oct 15 16:30:12 BRT 2012]; parent: com.bea.core.repackaged.springframework.context.support.GenericApplicationContext@885e019
    at com.oracle.pitchfork.inject.Jsr250Metadata.getUniqueInstanceOfType(Jsr250Metadata.java:304)
    at com.oracle.pitchfork.inject.Jsr250Metadata.resolveByType(Jsr250Metadata.java:298)
    at com.oracle.pitchfork.inject.Jsr250Metadata.resolve(Jsr250Metadata.java:285)
    at com.oracle.pitchfork.inject.Jsr250Metadata.applyInjections(Jsr250Metadata.java:235)
```

Important:

I use this EJB from a Webservice (in the same EAR), like:

```
.. class MyWebService.. {
 @EJB(name="GerencialFacadeBean", mappedName="GerencialFacade")
 private GerencialFacadeBeanLocal gerencialBean;

}
```

and, if I try got the datasource on the Webservice´s class it work sucessfully.

EDIT:

Another consideration: using REMOTE interface it works. But I want to use it with Local interface.

I'm using Weblogic 10.3.5. My Datasource is created and works fine in other applications (that get it directly by JNDI), So, what I´m getting this error?